# FS readable stream VS Axios responseType === 'stream'

Tags: node.js, axios, stream

I'm using a library that expects a NodeJS readable stream, as follows:

```
const transcription = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
  file: fs.createReadStream('./audio.mp3'),
  model: "whisper-1",
});
```

That code runs as expected. Now that audio.mp3 is a file that I downloaded from a URL first, placed it on the file system, and then created a read stream. Instead what I really want to do is to create a stream from the URL as pass it directly to the library, like this:

```
const { data: fileStream} = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });
const transcription = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
  file: fileStream,
  model: "whisper-1",
});
```

In theory this should be the same thing, but I must be missing something because this hangs the NodeJS process for several seconds and then the terminal goes crazy printing this several hundreds times:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Exception in
> PromiseRejectCallback:
> file:///home/domingo/WebstormProjects/call2jira-proxy/node_modules/openai/uploads.mjs:152
> }; ^

So there is clearly a difference between the stream from FS and the one from AXIOS.

PS: In case you suspect there is something wrong with the URL, here's where I'm reading the file from: https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACe77d4cec2fee4998a6f4f7bf9454fc54/Recordings/RE2024fd1091bfcbe858a6b9cc6d1b3ba5.mp3

Comment: Underlying openapi client actually does not pass on the provided stream directly to the `node:http` client. instead it uses toFile method described in docs internally to convert the stream back into a file. ref: https://github.com/openai/openai-node/blob/eddb2477178002fe35192627cb473f35c1e38086/src/uploads.ts#L145, so anyways you are not getting any benefits of using stream response from axios. but with that said, I can only guess that the stream returned from axios not having a proper async generator could cause this issue.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @v1shva